# Send email on a list of dates in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, email

In an Excel Online (Office 365) workbook, I have a sheet `reminders` with dates.

Clarification based on comments: Excel Online, in this context for me means that I am using Office 365, and the workbook is stored in the shared OneDrive.

| A |
| --- |
| date |
| 2023-07-15 |
| 2023-08-19 |

I would like to trigger an email from Excel if today matches one of the dates in this list. The email should be sent at 8am.

I understand how to send emails from Excel/VBA.

```
Public Sub SendEmailNow()

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim NewEmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set NewEmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

NewEmailItem.To = "to@company.com"

NewEmailItem.Subject = "Here's your reminder"

NewEmailItem.HTMLBody = "I am reminding you"

NewEmailItem.Send

End If
```

But after about an hour of Googling, I haven't been able to figure out **how to trigger** the emails at 8am on the dates in the list.

Comment: Are you searching for advice when to run your code or how you can set the date when the email is send?

Comment: You cannot  run vba with Online Excel, you can search the topic with office scripts.

Comment: VBA does not work online.

Comment: @Davesexcel I am using Office 365, and the workbook is stored in the shared OneDrive. Does this mean that for the VBA code to run, my local instance of Excel must be running at whatever time I need the email to be triggered?

Comment: @Tinman I am using Office 365, and the workbook is stored in the shared OneDrive. Does this mean that for the VBA code to run, my local instance of Excel must be running at whatever time I need the email to be triggered?

Comment: @FunThomas, I am looking for advice on how to make the email sending code to run on the dates specified in the sheet.

Comment: You would need to open it in the Desktop App to run the VBA and you will need the desktop app on your computer.  You would need to open it in the Desktop App to run the VBA and you will need the desktop app on your computer.  
 Alternately, you could use Office Script which is a JavaScript API for Office. 
 See:[How to send email in office 365 using office scripts or Excel Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/876163/how-to-send-email-in-office-365-using-office-scrip)

Comment: You could use delayed time in vba excel to accomplish this. It will send over the email to outlook  and wait until such date it will send only if PC is on and internet available . Do some googling on this...

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Microsoft 365, your license probably allow you to use Power Automate to capture data from Excel and integrate it with Outlook.

Either Excel Online and Power Automate on cloud don't support VBA, but it work fine with Office Scripts, which is the scripting tool for Excel web, performing a role similar to VBA in Excel Desktop.

You can check this article for more details about this relationship between VBA and Office Scripts: http://digitalmill.net/2023/06/10/office-scripts-the-new-vba/